# Implementing an indoor map

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, overlay

I would like to implement an indoor positioning system on an Android device (galaxy tab)

I have a picture of the map I intend to use. However I am not sure what is the right way to do 
this. 
I want my application to have some of the abilities of google maps, such as zoom and scroll, and the ability to use overlay items.

However, as I understand, it is not possible to use google maps with a custom map.
What is the right way to do this? Is there a library which enables us to zoom and scroll images/maps?
Can you use the overlay package without google maps? If not, how can you present a location in such a map?

Thanks in advance

Ariel

Comment: How are you planning to get the location for a indoor map. I think GPS wont be that accurate

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at these two Android apps:

[MapCalibrator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Martin.MapCalibrator&feature=search_result) by Martin Ohlin

[Custom Maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.custommapsapp.android&feature=nav_result) by Marlo Teittinen

To develop a full-blown indoor navigation system, have a look at these platforms:

http://insiteo.com/

http://cloudmade.com/

Googling aroud for "indoor positioning" and/or "indoor navigation" you will find many more solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If it was a large location - say a shopping centre - you could possibly map it out in a KML layer and add it to google maps but I'm not sure how well that would work. Google maps does not allow the user to zoom in very far - probably not far enough for your needs if you want to map down to the room level.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATfdi-oYWzw&noredirect=1) on "Map your business inside and out".

The google maps API v3 supports "custom maps"
[Discussions from the v3 group](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/search?group=google-maps-js-api-v3&q=custom+map&qt_g=Search+this+group)

[one example from a search](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_frm/thread/18c04a047858e7b0/e6081b4d76e33b7e?lnk=gst&q=custom+map#e6081b4d76e33b7e).