# Custom navigation on image map

Tags: android, navigation

I know similar question has been asked but i didn't found proper answer to what I`m looking for. I need to implement navigation on image map. The map is relatively small (5km X 5km), and the use will be able to pan and zoom on the map. Can you please point to right direction. How should I use the image (WebView, ImageView...) and general suggestions.

My client prefer not to use Google Maps API and Google MapView because he is says that is may some day will become not free, is it possible? I do not need to implement navigation and routing on the map. Just show user location on image. The map may be in 3D like view (it will be an image but the map will not be shown from above). There is high possibility that the map will be very large image, so that the user can zoom in, do I need to cut the image to squires and show only the relevant ones?

Comment: HI use can use indoor maps library http://insiteo.com/ & http://cloudmade.com/ mention by [AlexBottoni](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099882/implementing-an-indoor-map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, very little info here but I think we are talking about this scenario:

1. You want to develop a navigation application that does not use Google Maps API and Google MapView
2. Most likely, you will end up using ImageView to display your map image
3. You want to make possible for the user to get route directions on this custom map

In this case, you have to define a set of routes/pathways on your map and you will have to rely on some kind of pathfinding engine, like:

http://project-osrm.org/

The problem is: you are actually trying to re-implement a whole, custom-made navigation system, It is the kind of project that many student choose as their master thesys. It is hard and it is *large*. It will require you a lot of time and effort.

For inspiration, have a look at the tools that have been developed by the volunteers of OSM:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Software/Mobile

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, it is actually simpler. I do NOT wish to implement navigation on the map, just show the user location on an image. I will add more info to my question.

Comment: This is not easy, either. If you use MapView and Google Maps API (they must be used together) your can ask for location to Google but you *must* rely on Google Maps *only*. If you want to use your own map, you have to use your own location engine as well. Again, the main source of code/solution/info for this is OSM.