# Making an indoor map of a building on Android

Tags: android, dictionary, drawing, indoor-positioning-system

Basically I'd like to make an app that shows your location in a building. I am focusing on the map part right now.
It's my first attempt to make an android app but i think what i have in mind should work.
Basically what i want to do is to create a class for the several rooms with several attributes:

-name // to be able to label where you are

-position // (x,y) to indicate where the room 'starts'

-dimensions // [(x1,y1),.....,(xn,yn)] each point is a vertex of the room

-doors// [(x1,y1),.....,(xn,yn)] two points for a door.

-next room// to make sure later that the end of a room is the beginning of the next

-precendent room // same as before

Is it useful to have the "next room", "last room" attributes ? I'd just like to make sure there aren't any empty spaces but even in this case only one of them feel necessary. Also what would you advise me to use to draw that ?

Thank you

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099882/implementing-an-indoor-map

Comment: I'd really like to "do it from scratch", i don't want to use anything like google maps or mapbox, etc..

Comment: Do your research on routing algorithm. Google the related thesis on this topic and gather much information to build your own system from scratch!!!

Comment: I plan on routing only after making a map. I'll probably setup a directed graph and use a bellman ford to find the shortest path, but for now all I want to do is display a map. Then again i understand that having in mind what i want to do afterwards is important in order not to mess up right now.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to have next_room and last_room attributes in order to iterate through rooms (to *travel*), but may be easier to organize the data in an [ArrayList](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: ultimately i plan on making a "floor" class with an arraylist then a "building" class with several floors